# Clearing sessions on Plesk

Tags: php

I've got a PHP site and Plesk and I'm looking to destroy all the sessions (log out all users). How do I do this in Plesk or would I have to manually remove the files?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/94401/118258

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login to the Plesk database with:

"mysql -uadmin -p`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow` psa"

And delete all records in sessions table with
delete from sessions;

That's it.