# DNS on Plesk VDS and godaddy

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, godaddy

I've just purchased a virtual dedicated server with Plesk 9.
I have a portfolio of over 50 domains at godaddy and would like to use the VDS to host all of them.

I would like to use one of those 50 domains as nameserver (for example domain.com) so that i can enter ns1.domain.com and ns2.domain.com as nameservers for all domains in godaddy so i can set up hosting on my VDS.

How do i actually configure this one domain at godaddy? Do i use their TotalDNS service? Anyone can explain to me how i should proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a conflict in your question, you have 1 VDS but want to have 2 hosts, ns1 & ns2, as DNS servers.  You'll need two VDS if you want 2 hosts, best practice would be for the 2 hosts to be on separate physical machines in different geographic areas and networks.

Also, you don't need your own name servers to host on the VDS, you can use GoDaddy DNS and just set the records to point to the correct host. Since a DNS failure or misconfiguration will stop all traffic to the sites make sure you have good backups and understand how it works before you proceed.  If you still want to try it:

Get a public, static IP for your server.
On your OS of choice, install your DNS server of choice.
Configure the primary zone Domain.com in the DNS server.
Add the A record ns1.domain with your public IP.
Add a CNAME for www.domain.com to point to ns1.domain.com
Add an MX record(s) for wherever you can receive mail for domain.com.
In GoDaddy DNS config, set it to "Use Other DNS servers", enter ns1.domain.com for the first DNS server.
Allow pings to ns1 for testing.
Confirm that the zone/hosts are configured correctly by using digg/nslookup/ping to test.
Resolve errors.

Find another host to be ns2.domain.com with static IP.
On ns1, add an A record for ns2.domain.com.
On ns1, configure DNS server to allow ns2 to receive updates for each zone.
In GoDaddy DNS config, "Use Other DNS servers", enter ns2.domain.com for the second DNS server.
On ns2, in the DNS server, add a secondary zone for domain1.com, point to ns1 as the primary.
Confirm that the zone transfers correctly by using digg/nslookup/ping to test.
Resolve any errors.

For the other domains:
On ns1, add a primary zone for domain2.com in the DNS server.
Add an A record for www, and CNAMES for anything else you need on that host.
Add an MX record(s) for wherever you can receive mail for domain.com.
In GoDaddy DNS config, set it to "Use Other DNS servers", enter ns1.domain.com for the first DNS server.
Confirm that the zone/hosts are configured correctly by using digg/nslookup/ping to test.
Resolve errors.

Repeat for each domain.

On ns2, in the DNS server, add a secondary zone for each domain above, point to ns1 as the primary.
Confirm that the zone transfers correctly by using digg/nslookup/ping to test.
Resolve any errors.
Repeat.
Disable ping on ns1 and ns2 as you prefer.

Document, create offsite backups of ns1.
Make all future changes on ns1.

Comment: you are half right , why half ? cuz you can host yor NS1 and NS2 at the same machine , and assign each ns different ip ( supposing you have more than one ) and if not you can assign them same ip :) even tho this is not best practice ! but works most of the time :)

Comment: I see your point....your method will work, but I think it's a really bad idea.  If there isn't enough money for 2 servers, or a separate hosted DNS service, then the DNS should stay at the registrar where it's already free.  In your plan the MX for 50 domains will sit on 1 VDS, if that server goes down or DNS stops working then no email for 50 domains.  That includes no email to domain.com, which is probably the admin/technical contact for the registrar. The restore process with 2 DNS servers is easy, with 1 it probably won't be.  I think we'll have to agree to disagree on this one.

Comment: yes , you are 100% right , its bad idea , but for few domains it works , especially if its nothing important , but if its some business site the dns must be as you said , on two different networks :)